# HTML5 image wont display

Tags: html

I am using notepad ++ for starters. I created a parent folder in my documents where I save my code, within that folder I created a subfolder to store images.

Below is the code I am using

```
 <section>
     <img src="img/vietnam.jpg"
</section>
```

Why won't it display? I have named the image vietnam.jpg in my subfolder :S

Comment: Add > after .jpg" to close the image tag.

Comment: How exactly are you running your code?

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly I am saving it in my parent folder and then clicking on it to test it from the documents folder, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML source file (e.g. index.html) is in the folder c:\Users\Patricia\Documents\adv, then as your img folder is a subfolder of \adv, the following should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <img src="img/vietnam.jpg" alt="vietnam">
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the path to your HTML source parent folder?

Comment: Thanks Dan, I used the absolute path technique earlier and its up and running now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue it could be because your are not getting to the right path where your image lives. 
If you have, for instance, your html file contained in a folder which is at the same level of your img folder then you should add `../` in order to get up one level and then specify which folder you would like to get into, in this case `img` folder.

Ex.:

```
<section>
  <img src="../img/vietnam.jpg" alt="vietnam">
</section>

    /   = Root directory
    .   = This location
    ..  = Up a directory
    ./  = Current directory
    ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```

Comment: I literally tried everything, this is where the image I want to use lives, I tried all of the above but still nothing :( C:\Users\Patricia\Documents\adv\img

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all i would suggest you to switch your code editor (e.g. to VisualStudio code as it is one of the editors used/preferred widely in the industries. Of course there's other Editrs/IDE's like WebStorm and so on ). Basically with the right plugins/configurations you will fasty become a superhero. For example, look at the screen below. I used relative path in VisualStudio and it shows the current path you're currently in.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDCDu.png)

Comment: That looks so much easier, but I am not allowed to use it; this is for a college assignment! :S Thanks for the suggestion though, I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the closing bracket of img-tag, which leads to invalid html that cant be displayed properly

look at the example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

```
<img src="/img/vietnam.jpg" >
```

Comment: Thanks John, I tried that, but no luck. I have copied below my entire code up until I tried to add images it all worked perfectly I just don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: use an absolute path `/img/vietnam.jpg` instead of `img/vietnam.jpg`